# Error on install angular cli 7 on mac osx Mojave

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, angular-cli-v7

I'm having error on install angular@cli on Mac Osx Mojave 10.14.5 with node version 10.15.3 and npm 6.9.0

I've also tried to remove and reinstall node and npm, and follow this article [Error installing angular/cli on macOS mojave - node-pre-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349679/error-installing-angular-cli-on-macos-mojave-node-pre-gyp)

```
npm install -g @angular/cli 
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli 

npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/fabiodigiuseppe/.npm/_logs/2019-05-26T15_39_28_869Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who find this problem during installation, i've resolved by install angular/cli with this:

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm